# Detecting the reference types in a tuple

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, boost-tuples

I learned about `std::forward_as_tuple`. I use this tech in my project:

```
template<class... Ts>
tuple<Ts&&...> values(Ts&&... ts) // yes, values is renamed forward_as_tupe
{
    return tuple<Ts&&...>(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...)
}

class C_SQL { ...... }; // MySQL C API, SQL statement encapsulation
                        // operator% is well defined.

char pszname[32];
int  iage;

C_SQL sql;
sql % "insert into student (name,age,grade)"
    %  values(pszname, iage, 2 );
```

Then, I can get a MySQL C API Prepared Statement string like this:

> ```
> "insert into student (name,age,grade) values(？, ？, 2 )"
> ```

"pszname" and "iage" are lvalues, so they are binding variables. `2` is an rvalue, so I can tell that it's a literal in an SQL statement.

My question is:

How can I tell if an element in a tuple is an rvalue or an lvalue?

For example:

```
int k;
tuple<int&, int&&> t = forward_as_tuple(k, 2);
```

The first element is an lvalue-reference, the second is an rvalue-reference.

Please use C++ code to tell that. The code can deal with varaidic template tuple.

Comment: Sorry for the multiple edits! Now if I understand correctly, you want to detect if the elements in a tuple are an lvalue or an rvalue. What exactly are you planning to do with this information?

Comment: @0x499602D2: As I understand, it is to fill `values(..)` content. (`？` or direct value).

Comment: @Jarod42 is always right. This question also indicates that rvalue reference element of tuple is not useless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of useful traits in `#include <type_traits>`. You are probably interested in `std::is_rvalue_reference` and `std::is_lvalue_reference`.

For example, to check if the first type is an rvalue:

```
bool r0 = std::is_rvalue_reference<std::tuple_element<0, decltype(t)>::type>::value;
```

Answer (score 3):

you may use

```
std::is_rvalue_reference<std::tuple_element<Index, MyTuple>::type>::value
std::is_lvalue_reference<std::tuple_element<Index, MyTuple>::type>::value
```